# get the full url name

Tags: php, server

I am trying to get the full url name for example

https://example.com/index.php?page=home

I use this code

```
$curPageName = substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
```

and this code

```
<a href="https://example.com/<?php echo $curPageName; ?>" title="Check this site in English">
```

Unfortunately the result comes out as

https://example.com/index.php

the rest or url "?page=home" is missing. How can I get this included? its not just only one page like ?page=home is has more pages. Do I miss something in substr($_SERVER["SCRIPTNAME"] ???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the full URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use [$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

```
https://google.com/foo/bar/?test=3
```

returns

```
/foo/bar/?test=3
```

In a link: `<a href="https://example.com<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" title="Link">`

A few notes about using this:

1. ***Be aware that the client can set REQUEST_URI to any value***
2. REQUEST_URI might include the scheme and domain when calling the page through stream_context_create() with a HTTP header of 'request_fulluri' set to 1.

Additional Questions:

1. [How do I capture the whole URL using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355305/how-do-i-capture-the-whole-url-using-php)
2. [Get the full URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help. Please mark the answer correct if you consider the question answered

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to get the query string and make a function that inserts a `?` if there are indeed values in the query.

```
function get_query_string() {
   $query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
   if(strlen($query) > 0) {
      $query = "?" . $query;
   }
   return $query;
}
$curPageName = substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1) . get_query_string();
```